# When is the SAMA 21 CD coming out?

Tags: album, cd, pop, release

When is the 21st South African Music Awards Nominees CD coming out? The winners were [announced](http://citizen.co.za/342803/sama-21-nominees-announced/) in March this year already (2015).

Answer (score 2):

I contacted a music store chain in South Africa, and they said:

> We cannot confirm that there will be one this year as there was no word on the CD from the supplier.